# How to read Gmail contacts using Zend Framework using oAuth

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth, gmail

I am done with oAuth with Google using Zend Framework. For now i am reading user google DOCs only. How can i read Gmail contacts using Zend Framework withour asking username and password.

Thank You a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any straight forward way to do that. You can try this [solution](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-phpgooglecontact/index.html). But this uses username & pwd. You can refer to this [Calendar](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html) example for how to authenticate using both ways.

Answer (score 0):

oAuth is about authentication, so you will have to authenticate providing credentials.

Authentication is not possible without username and password.

However, you can use API to access the data:

- http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/contacts/
- http://googledataapis.blogspot.com/2008/03/3-2-1-contact-api-has-landed.html